# How do I delete directories for a specific time period (say older than one month) using dos command?

Tags: dos, dir

I am trying to delete directories older than one month from a batch file.
I am able to list directory names using:

dir D:* /A:D-H

But not sure how can I delete them for a specific time.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `forfiles` command.

Syntax:

`FORFILES [/p Path] [/m Mask] [/s] [/c Command] [/d [+ | -] {dd/MM/yyyy | dd}]`

The following command
`forfiles /p "C:\source_folder" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -30` will erase files in `c:\source_folder` older than 30 days.

See more examples and explications [here](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

SET FOLDERPATH="F:\TestEnvir\bin\backup\MarketData\D"
rem FORFILES /p %FOLDERPATH% /S /D 30 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"